# Find first one million prime numbers

Tags: objective-c, primes

I want to get the first one million prime numbers.

I know the way of finding small prime numbers. My problem is, how can I store such large numbers in simple data types such as long, int, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the millionth prime is less than 16 million, and with the amount of memory in today's computers an ordinary C array of 16 million booleans (you can use 1 byte for each) isn't that large...

So allocate your large array, fill it with true's, treat the first element as representing the integer 2 (i.e. index + 2 is the represented value), and implement the skip n/set false version of the standard sieve. Count the true's as you go and when you get to 1 million you can stop.

There are others ways, but this has the merit of being simple.

Comment: Just to add to the answer - there may be other ways, but I think that this is nearly the fastest way to generate a list of sequential primes. There are other algorithms to test specific numbers for primeness that perform better than a sieve, but for generating a list, I'm not sure you can do much better outside of skipping all the even numbers, and possibly every third, fifth, ... But the code complexity to take that approach quickly outweighs the benefit...

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate an array of 1000000 integers - it is only four megabytes, a small number by today's standards. Prime #1000000 should fit in a 32-bit integer (prime #500000 is under 8000000, so 2000000000 should be more than enough of a range for the first 1000000 primes).

You are more likely to encounter issues with the time, not with the space for your computation. Remember that you can stop testing candidate divisors when you reach the square root of the candidate prime, and that you can use the primes that you found so far as your candidate divisors.